# Notion of a limit for a sequence of matrices growing in both dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose $\{M_{N_1,N_2}\}$ is a sequence of $N_1 \times N_2$ matrices whose elements are non-negative and are bounded from above by $1$. I wonder if there is a way to define a notion of convergence and a corresponding limit for this  sequence of matrices as $N_1, N_2 \rightarrow \infty$.

I first thought about putting all the rows of the matrix consecutively in a long sequence and then making that sequence infinite by adding an infinite number of zeros and thinking about convergence in sequence spaces but from the answers kindly given to my earlier questions here it became clear that something like this would not work for an application I have in mind...

The question is... is there any other way to proceed with defining a limit and a convergence notion?

Answer (score 1):

One of the approaches:

Let $S$ be a space of number sequences. Consider your matrices $M_{n_1,n_2}$ as linear operators on $S$ as follows: take a sequence $b$, cut off first $n_2$ entries, act on them by your matrix $M_{n_1,n_2}$, obtain $n_1$ entries, then project them on $S$ by filling the tail of the number sequence with zeros.

If you introduce a norm on $S$ ($\ell_p$, weighted $\ell_p$, or something else), then you can induce an operator norm, and then consider the convergence of your sequence of matrices $M$ in that operator norm.

Comment: This sounds like a very interesting idea I shall explore. Thanks!

Comment: Dear @TZakrevskiy, I suppose that when using operator norms as a basis for this type of convergence one could also have a notion of a partial limit, right?

Comment: Yes. In fact, if your normed space of sequences is complete ($\ell_p$, for example) then  the space of linear bounded operators on it with the induced operator norm is complete, so you have quite a variety of instruments at your disposal.